# Jquery nested tagLib

Tags: jquery-plugins, struts2, taglib

Ho there, can someone explain how to make this code working??

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-jquery-tags" prefix="sj"%>

<s:iterator value="familiari" var="entry">
    <sj:accordion id="familiare<s:property value="#entry.index" />">
       <sj:accordionItem title="abc">
            content
    </sj:accordionItem>
   </sj:accordion>
</s:iterator>
```

this row does not work:

```
<sj:accordion id="familiare<s:property value="#entry.index" />">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/AccordionTag

You need to provide a list for your accordion item.  I don't know what `familiari` is but if you are iterating through it, I assume it's a list of some kind so you can try:

```
<sj:accordion id="familiare list="familiari"/>
```

If you are looking to iterate over a list and provide a form within each accordion. You can try something like the following:

```
<sj:accordion id="someId">
    <s:iterator value="familiari" var="entry">
        <sj:accordionItem title="abc">
            <s:form action...>
                <s:hidden name="somePropertyFromCurrentIterationElement" value="%{getIndex()}"/>
                ...
            </s:form>
        </sj:accordionItem>
    </s:iterator>
</sj:accordion>
```

Comment: OK, but if I wanto to insert a form inside each accordion. How cai I procede?

Comment: @Angelodev: do you also need to iterate over a list at the same time?

Comment: @Angelodev: you could do something like 

`<sj:accordion id="someId">
    <s:iterator value="familiari" var="entry">
        <sj:accordionItem title="abc">
            <s:form action...>
                <s:hidden name="somePropertyFromCurrentIterationElement" value="%{getIndex()}"/>
                ...
            </s:form>
        </sj:accordionItem>
    </s:iterator>
</sj:accordion>`

I'll add to the answer above so that it's more readable.

Comment: I have to iterate on each alement of the list, and use the entry field to populate a form. The relation is 1 to 1 between an entry list and the form inside the accordion

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Tags inside of tags. Use Ognl instead.

```
<sj:accordion id="familiare%{entry.index}">
```